# How can fetch data from encoded array in blade file

Tags: php, laravel

I have sending array in the object
How can fetch some data from array in blade file

Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $projects = Project::get();
    return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
}
```

Blade file

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $project->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $project->servers }}</td>   
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

servers in a encoded array which are saving in database in which should only name which I will list

I have data in servers array after
**dd(json_decode($project->servers));**

```
{#1232 ▼
  +"id": 494506
  +"identifier": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
  +"name": "test"
  +"protocol_type": "ftp"
  +"server_path": "htdocs"
  +"auto_deploy_url": "https://adamw.deployhq.com/deploy/codebase-project/to/test/xxxxxxxxxxx"
  +"last_revision": "abcdef123456"
  +"preferred_branch": "master"
  +"branch": null
  +"notify_email": null
  +"server_group_identifier": null
  +"hostname": "ftp.test.com"
  +"username": "test"
  +"port": 21
  +"passive": true
  +"force_hidden_files": false
}
```

Comment: ?? `$project->servers` I see no ships

Comment: `{{ $project->servers->name }}`

Comment: sounds like you want to cast this particular field to an array on the model so it will be decoded for you   https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the model to cast this field to an array which will decode the JSON for you:

```
protected $casts = [
    'servers' => 'array',
];
```

Though if this variable isn't going to be holding multiple servers perhaps it should be named 'server' instead of 'servers'.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Mutators - Array and JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

Comment: Thanks for replying me..
Bro i'm saving servers encoded json array in the project table with attribute servers
and I want to get only name from the servers array

Comment: How can use this veriable in blade file